# How to migrate old statistics to google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking, analytics-api, analytics-events

In our project we stored all users event data in our database for over one year , but it's not indexed.

now we are going to use google analytics to store our analytics and analyze the report using google analytics dashboard.

but before start using google analytics , i would like to emigrate all old statics (about 2 million events) to google analytics.

for this matter i should use [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) and it's limit allow me to transfer 2 million hits with no problem.

but i didn't succeed to know how to set the time of the event. Measurement Protocol has [Queue Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) but google says :

> Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

how it's possible to transfer **2 million events** to google analytics with there **event time** ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this step by step. I think that the biggest problem is in data structure. You need to check that out. And also, I'm not sure if it can handle 2 million events at once. (Never had that many events for import) :)

http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/09/28/google-analytics-data-import-guide/